# PowerShell - Loop through excel files and change sheet names

Tags: powershell

I am trying to come up with a script to loop through excel files in a folder and change the tab names in each file.

e.g
13 files in a folder, loop through each file and if a sheet name is ABC change to XYZ, if a sheet name is CDE change to PRQ etc.

This is what i have so far, but i cant figure out how to change the tab names. positioning of the sheet names has no particular order.

```
param
(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$InputPath

)

Get-ChildItem $InputPath 


$ExcelObject=New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$ExcelObject.DisplayAlerts = $false
$ExcelFiles=Get-ChildItem -Path $InputPath -Filter *.xlsx


foreach ($ExcelFile in $ExcelFiles){
$Everyexcel=$ExcelObject.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFile.FullName)
$worksheet = $Everyexcel.Worksheet.item(1)
if ($worksheet.Name="ABC")
{
 ($worksheet.Name="XYZ")
}
}
```

Comment: "if a sheet name is ABC change to XYZ, if a sheet name is CDE change to PRQ etc." - can you expand a little bit on the logic employed here? Why those particular mappings?

Comment: they are just examples i used

Comment: Okay, but what are you gonna use in real life? Do you have a CSV file with the real life mappings? Or a set of rules?

Comment: I was looking to hardcode the values, but i could create a csv with the values. not sure how i would implement that though. a real example is tab name = 'AssetDetailRegSecGSC' , id like to rename this to 'Risk Region Sector'

Answer (score 1):

Define a hashtable literal with your name mappings - existing sheet names as keys, new names as values:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$InputPath
)

$sheetNames = @{
    'AssetDetailRegSecGSC' = 'Risk Region Sector'
    'SomethingElse'        = 'Whatever New Name Is Desired'
    # ... and so on...
}

$ExcelObject = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
try {
    $ExcelObject.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $ExcelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $InputPath -Filter *.xlsx

    foreach ($ExcelFile in $ExcelFiles) {
        # open workbook
        $workbook = $ExcelObject.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFile.FullName)
        try {
            # loop through each sheet in the workbook
            foreach ($worksheet in $workbook.Worksheets) {
                # change sheet name if found in mapping table
                if ($sheetNames.ContainsKey($worksheet.Name)) {
                    $worksheet.Name = $sheetNames[$worksheet.Name]
                }
                else {
                    Write-Warning "Unrecognized sheet name in '$($ExcelFile.FullName)': '$($worksheet.Name)'"
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            # close workbook and save changes
            $workbook.Close($true)
        }
    }
}
finally {
    # remember to close excel
    $ExcelObject.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelObject)
}
```

Comment: this worked! thanks so much for your help. do you know if its possible set the position of the sheets within this script as well?